# D3.js Force Directed Graph: Issue with updating node colors when hexColor is null

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a D3.js force-directed graph where nodes can have a hexColor field, which sometimes contains a hex value as a string, and other times is null. I'm trying to update the colors of the nodes based on this hexColor field, but I'm encountering an issue when the hexColor is null.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
initChart() {
this.node = this.scene.append("g")
        .attr("stroke", "#fff")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .selectAll("circle");
}

updateChart({nodes, edges}) {
      const old = new Map(this.node.data().map(d => [d.id, d]));
      nodes = nodes.map(d => ({...old.get(d.id), ...d}));
      edges = edges.map(d => ({...d}));

this.node = this.node
        .data(nodes, d => d.id)
        .join(enter => enter.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 8)
          .attr("fill", d => d.hexColor ?? "#537B87")//TODO node coloring changes doesnt work
          .call(this.drag(this.simulation))
          .call(node => node.append("title")
            .text(d => `IP: ${d.name} ${d.tags ? `\nTags: ${d.tags}` : ''}`))
        );
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the color is not being updated when the updateChart method is triggered.

How can I modify my code to achieve this behavior?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an update callback in your `.join`.  The enter callback is only called when the node is initially added.

```
this.node = this.node
     .data(nodes, d => d.id)
     .join(
         enter => enter.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 8)          
          .call(this.drag(this.simulation))
          .call(node => node.append("title")
            .text(d => `IP: ${d.name} ${d.tags ? `\nTags: ${d.tags}` : ''}`)),
         update => update.attr("fill", d => d.hexColor ?? "#537B87")
        );
```